# Why is my service running as root

Tags: systemd, users, services

I have an old laptop hooked up to my router running as linux box. I installed qbittorrent to run as a remote torrent box (to download linux distros of course) and I created a new user, "qbuser" for it to run under.  I created the appropriate unit file but when I look at the process list, it's running as root. Why this might be happening?
[image: result of top command]

```
[Unit]
Description=qbittorrent-nox
Documentation=man:qbittorrent-nox
DefaultDependencies=yes
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
Before=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=[i][b]qbuser[/b][/i]
Group=[b]qb[/b]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/qbittorrent-nox [-options]
Nice=10
StandardError=null
StandardOutput=null
TimeoutSec=360s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Edit: I fixed the syntax errors in the unit file, now it just fails outright. I double checked that group qb and user qbuser exist.  Here is the systemctl status output:

```
steve@debian-server:~$ sudo systemctl status qbittorrent
● qbittorrent.service - qbittorrent-nox
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/qbittorrent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Fri 2019-01-25 23:31:07 CST; 6min ago
     Docs: man:qbittorrent-nox
  Process: 994 ExecStart=/usr/bin/qbittorrent-nox (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 994 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

Jan 25 23:31:07 debian-server systemd[1]: Started qbittorrent-nox.
Jan 25 23:31:07 debian-server systemd[1]: qbittorrent.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Jan 25 23:31:07 debian-server systemd[1]: qbittorrent.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 25 23:31:07 debian-server systemd[1]: qbittorrent.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Comment: Check the output of `systemctl status qbittorrent-nox`, as it might explain what is going on. Edit the description and paste it here, that might help us help you understand it. Your paste includes `[i][b]` markers, I'm expecting that's an artifact of your copy & paste, right? If they're really there, then that would explain why this isn't running as the specified user...

Comment: Oh crap, that's not actually supposed to be there? I had copied and pasted from another SO post.  It worked without throwing any errors so I didn't think there was anything wrong with the syntax

Comment: That's not supposed to be there, no. Also the `[-options]` part, you probably should replace that with your own options (and remove the square brackets.) If the user does not exist, systemd will log a warning and keep going as root. You'll see the log with the `systemctl status qbittorrent-nox` command.

Comment: @filbranden I fixed all that, now it just fails outright

Comment: does user `qbuser` have a valid home directory? See this post here: https://qbforums.shiki.hu/index.php/topic,3840.msg19535.html?PHPSESSID=a0c29829c4958661bd87d3e1ef73e9d4#msg19535

Comment: `status=6/ABRT` means qbittorrent-nox is aborting calling the `abort();` function... This is typically done when something went very wrong. If qbittorrent-nox is saving other logs, try checking those.

Comment: I figured out the problem I think.  When I created qbuser's home directory(manually, after I created the acocunt) I didn't change the ownership so it doesn't have rw permissions in its own home directory.  Will let you know if it works

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the extra characters around the user and group name in your unit.

Instead of:

```
[Service]
User=[i][b]qbuser[/b][/i]
Group=[b]qb[/b]
```

You should use:

```
[Service]
User=qbuser
Group=qb
```

(Assuming group `qb` exists.)

Also the `[-options]` part, you probably should replace that with your own options (and remove the square brackets.)

If the user does not exist, systemd will log a warning and proceed running the service as root.

You can see the logs with the warning using the `systemctl status qbittorrent-nox` command, or `journalctl -u qbittorrent-nox -e` to show more of the logs.